# How do I set up a virtual network with internet access in VMware?

Tags: windows, networking, vmware-workstation

My current VMware setup looks like this:

[image: My VMware]

"Host" is my PC and "Win Server", "PC1", and "PC2" are all running in a VMware environment.

How do I give my VM's internet access while also being able to receive DHCP and DNS from my Win Server?

I don't want my "Host" Ethernet network to receive anything related to DHCP and DNS from my Win Server.

So far I only use a custom Network adapter(VMnet4) on all my VM's.

Comment: It's not clear how you have everything set up. Are the Win Server, the PC1, and the PC2 all virtualised by the host, as shown in your picture? Is your goal to prevent packets from PC1, PC2, and Win Server from hitting the ethernet?

Comment: Yes exactly I want to use my Win server to test a bunch of stuff like dhcp, dns and so on, but I also want internet access at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a virtual network (like your VMNet4) to enable communication between your virtual machines. You should use a virtual network that is not used for other purposes (NAT, Host-only, Bridged, ...). Since you probably want your “Win Server” VM to do DHCP and all, no further setup is required.

You also need another adapter on your “Win Server” VM. Depending on how isolated you actually want it to be, it could either be NAT (more isolated) or Bridged Networking (no isolation). This adapter will enable Internet connectivity.